# Paypal integration without IPN

Tags: asp.net, paypal, paypal-ipn

I want to integrate paypal buy now button *and get feedback from paypal* in a school project, but i don't want to use IPN because the computer running the website will not be accessible from outside.

Are there any options for doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to enable IPN to have buy now buttons on Paypal, it's completely optional. The buy now button will still take you to the correct page on Paypal so the purchase can be made. IPN only allows you to get feedback from Paypal when this happens.

---

> Well, I need to get some information
>   when a successful payment is made.

Paypal can notify you by mail when something has happened.

Comment: Well, I need to get some information when a successful payment is made.

Answer (score 2):

Apologies for the bump. Just adding this in case anyone else needs it:

Use "rm=2". (input type hidden, name=rm, value=2)

https://merchant.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables

Return method. The FORM METHOD used to send data to the URL specified by the return variable after payment completion. Allowable values:
0 – all shopping cart transactions use the GET method
1 – the payer’s browser is redirected to the return URL by the GET method, and no transaction variables are sent
2 – the payer’s browser is redirected to the return URL by the POST method, and all transaction variables are also posted